# Do you perform test when you code a project alone?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, functional-testing

I wonder if individual programmer would spend time doing unit test, functional test or applying test driven development (TDD) method when they code alone. Or, he just bother about getting it work.

Reason I ask because having those tests do prolong the entire project.

Thanks.

Comment: I've coded a compression algorithm of 3 layers and I haven't used a single test. Damnation. That's the only thing I'm going to say about that.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that if I don't do unit tests, that prolongs the project a thousand times more. I always want to just get the feature working, then the next feature, then the next. It takes work for me to have the discipline to do unit tests, even though I've proved to myself over and over again that those tests form the golden road to timely completion.

Answer (score 2):

The benefits of testing are the same whether you are a team or a sole developer.

Therefore the magic answer is this: **it is totally up to you**.

The only real difference between the two scenarios is when you are developing by yourself you do not have to convince anyone else to write or not write tests, you can simply have that argument with yourself.

Comment: I think the problem over here is cost vs time. If we have a team, we can dedicate a test engineer.

Comment: If you are using TDD, the developers would typically write the tests, not a test engineer. And I would reframe the "cost vs time" remark: how much testing you want to do is about whether it's more costly to find a bug later or earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer doing TDD coz the API's of some modules are not defined in beginning and writing the UI while writing the API for the data module is a little confusing at times.

so I tend to create the data module API's by writing the test cases for it.  I also use it to measure progress. once that is done. the UI gets complete fairly quick and debugging the UI gets a lot lot lot faster as data part is already tested.

while the offset with the test case development is more, the debugging time it saves is good amount and gives a comfortable development flow.

Answer (score 1):

It depends :)

- If it is a **prototype/ proof of concept** / tech that I am trying to learn. I'd usually **not choose TDD** because it's a throw-away. (Learning tests for third party libs that I am trying to integrate into my app are an exception.)
- If it is something that I need to sustain for a longer duration of time (more than a month), I'd pick TDD. If multiple people are going to work on it in the future, I'd definitely pick TDD

That said, TDD does not automatically imply good apps/design/insert-good-metric here. Good/Experienced programmers write good software. With TDD, they're more likely to be better/faster.